# Integration with respect to the variance of a normal random variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, integral

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $f$ a measureable function on $[a, b]$.

For $t \in [a, b]$, we know that $f(t) X$ has distribution $N(0, f(t)^2)$.

Is it true that $\int_a^b f(t)X dt$ has distribution $N\left(0, (\int_a^b f(t)dt)^2\right)$?

I believe that should be true, but I'm not sure how it can be formally verified. Are there any assumptions that are needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_a^b f(t) X \, dt = \left(\int_a^b f(t) \, dt\right)\cdot  X$. (This holds for each realization of the random variable $X$.)

The integral $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt$ is just a number, say $c$, and the distribution of $cX$ is  $N(0, c^2)$.